# React Storybook not working on Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am just following the [get started guide](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/get-started/) for Storybook with React.

When I run the command **yarn run storybook**, I get an error:

> Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "storybook".

I have tried on my Macbook, and it works fine everytime, so I am not sure whay it is doing that.
I have spent the past 2 hours looking for a solution but cannot find anything.

EDIT: I have tried `yarn storybook` as well, but doesn't work.

EDIT 2: Adding `package.json` contents bellow:

```
{
  "name": "taskbox",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running that command inside a project folder with a `packages.json` file? according to the [yarn site](https://legacy.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/) you'll need one and define the script.

Comment: @Stutje Yes, I am inside my project when I run the command. I did the exact same thing on my Macbook and it works no problem, Storybook launches, but on Windows it errors.

Comment: Same problem with `yarn storybook` command? With no `run`?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli Yes, I tried both `yarn storybook` and `yarn run storybook`, doesn't like it.

Comment: Can you provide the full output of the command and the `package.json`?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli The full output is `Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "storybook".` and I have added the `package.json`.

Comment: @squeekyDave no storybook script under the scripts section?

Comment: @Stutje I am just comparing the `package.json` from my Macbook and indeed there is a script for storybook, which is missing from my Windows project.

Comment: @squeekyDave can you re-copy/pull your project again to your windows machine and try again, to avoid other missing parts?

Comment: @Stutje I have just copied the `package.json` from my working project, removed the `node_modules`, did fresh install and now I can see storybook opening but it doesnt show any stories, everything is loading.

Comment: was you able to fix this issue @squeekyDave   ...i am facing same issues on  windows 10..if yes please provide the anwer

Comment: @SamikshaJagtap I couldn’t find solution. Keep in mind this was months ago so maybe now you would be able to find more information

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to create a fresh project on my Windows machine that runs Storybook with React.

I have created mutliple projects on my Mac machine and everything is fine, then I repeat the exact same process on my Windows Machine and it seems only the React app is being created, but Storybook is not being added.

There are no errors, it shows a success message that Storybook has been added and thats it. All of the Storybook folders/files and dependencies do not get added.

I have created a project on my Mac and pushed it into Git, then pulled on my Windows machine and everything seems to be fine.

At this point I am not sure if my Windows machine is causing problems or Storybook just doesn't play well with Wondows.